# Deserialize JSON with a list of two objects, one being a list of that object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to de-serialize a weird complex json string but having issues. I am getting an exception:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Response' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})

The Json looks like this

```
{  
   "success":true,
   "error":null,
   "response":{  
      "responses":[  
         {  
            "success":true,
            "error":null,
            "response":{  
               "ob":{  
                  "icon":"sunny.png",
                  "weatherShort":"Sunny"
               }
            },
            "request":"requeststring"
         },
         {  
            "success":true,
            "error":null,
            "response":[  
               {  
                  "indice":{  
                     "current":{  
                        "dateTimeISO":"2016-08-09T10:00:00-05:00",
                        "indexENG":"dry"
                     }
                  }
               }
            ],
            "request":"requeststring"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

The problem when trying to create a C# class is that inside the responses list there is a Response object and a Response list.

Here is my class structure:

```
public class Responses
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public object error { get; set; }
    public Response response { get; set; }
    public List<Response> responses { get; set; }
    public string request { get; set; }
}

public class Indice
{
    public Current current { get; set; }
}

public class Current
{
    public string indexENG { get; set; }
    public string dateTimeISO { get; set; }
}

public class Ob
{
    public string icon { get; set; }
    public string weatherShort { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public List<Responses> responses { get; set; }
    public Indice indice { get; set; }
    public Ob ob { get; set; }
}

public class RootJsonObject
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public object error { get; set; }
    public Response response { get; set; }
}
```

Am I doing something completely wrong here to handle the **Responses** list with a **Response** object and a **Response** list?

In case anyone wants to know, here is how I deserialize it:

```
RootJsonObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootJsonObject>(response);
```

response being the string from a web request.

I am just trying to figure out how to map this strange JSON to a C# class. I've tried quite a few different class structures but seem to get the same exception regardless. I've also tried c# class generators but they don't give a decent output for this particular JSON. Appreciate any input! Thanks!

Comment: That JSON is pretty weird - because the structure varies even between the two nested responses. The first nested response is a JSON object; the second nested response is a JSON array. What's creating this JSON in the first place, and can you fix it to be more consistent?

Comment: Unfortunately not, this is an API that I use. I will definitely share this with them and see if they will fix it. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something wrong before addressing a JSON issue on their end. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your JSON. Second element in array has square brackets wrapping classic curly brackets, as if `response` was a collection but it's not. It's expected to be of type `Response`:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "error": null,
    "response": [ <<<HERE {
        "indice": {
            "current": {
                "dateTimeISO": "2016-08-09T10:00:00-05:00",
                "indexENG": "dry"
            }
        }
    }] <<<HERE,
    "request": "requeststring"
}
```

Final, proper JSON that **you should have received** would look like this:

```
{
    'success': true,
    'error': null,
    'response': {
        'responses': [{
            'success': true,
            'error': null,
            'response': {
                'ob': {
                    'icon': 'sunny.png',
                    'weatherShort': 'Sunny'
                }
            },
            'request': 'requeststring'
        }, {
            'success': true,
            'error': null,
            'response': {
                'indice': {
                    'current': {
                        'dateTimeISO': '2016-08-09T10:00:00-05:00',
                        'indexENG': 'dry'
                    }
                }
            },
            'request': 'requeststring'
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Turns out they have a different call which puts the first response as an array, so that way it can be deserialized correctly. Strange, but it works. Thanks for the answer!